# create list nest from each column of pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, arraylist

Here is simple of my dataframe

```
                  A    B     C    D    
Date                                                                         
1                 A1   B1    C1   D1 
2                 A2   B2    C2   D2 
3                 A3   B3    C3   D3 
4                 A4   B4    C4   D4
```

so i want to create nest list like `[[A1,A2,A3,A4],[B1,B2,B3,B4],....]`

i use command like `mylist = dataframe.value.tolist()`

but it return `[[A1,B1,C1,D1],[A2,B2,C2,D2]]` instead

so is there a way to get nest list as i want?

#i use python 3.8.5 and pandas dataframe import data from yfinance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transpose and then call `values`:

```
df.T.values.tolist()

[['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
 ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
 ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
 ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through columns and append

```
li = []
for col in dataframe:
    li.append(dataframe[col])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solutions for your problem:

```
l=[]
for e in df.columns:
    column = df[e].values.tolist()
    l.append(column)
```

The idea is taking every column as a list, and iterate it for all de columns.